# How to write Nant script for publish the code and it should use sql server authentication

Tags: sql-server, nant

I am successful in writing the `Nant` script to Publish the code for `Database`.

```
<project name="Local-Deploy" basedir="." default="publish_code">

<property name="MSBuildPath" value="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe"/>
<property name="Solution_file_path" value="xxx.WebUI/xxxWebUI.csproj"/>
<property name="Published_path" value="C:\demo\Publish_code"/>
<target name="publish_code">
        <exec program="${MSBuildPath}">
            <arg line='"${Solution_file_path}"'/>
            <arg line='/property:Configuration="TEST";DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=Local-Deploy;_PackageTempDir=${Published_path}'/>
          <arg value="/target:Build" />  
        </exec>

</target>
</project>
```

How can I write `Nant` script for publish the code to target Database connection should be `xxx.amazonaws.com` and it should use SQL server authentication with username `XXX` and Password `xxx`.

Please suggest me.

Thanks is advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

As per : [Using NAnt to deploy the database](http://hallertech.com/nant/index.html#database-build):

```xml
<target name="test">
    <property name="test.script" value="${dir.sql}/test.sql"/>
    <property name="test.connstring" 
        value="Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=localhost;Database=nHello;User ID=nHelloUser;Password=showme"/>
    <echo file="${test.script}" message="execute p_GetMessage;"/>
    <echo message="* Connecting to ${test.connstring}"/>
    <echo message="* Executing ${path::get-file-name(test.script)}"/>
    <sql connstring="${test.connstring}" delimiter=";" delimstyle="Normal" source="${test.script}"/>
  </target>
```